# PowerShell set literalpath as parameter path

Tags: windows, powershell

Пробую выполнить эту команду

```
new-item -Path (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath "C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe") -Name "OHW" -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

Но получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я указал неверный параметр, правильно было написать команду так:

```bash
New-Item -Target 'C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe' -Path .\OHW.lnk -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я указал неверный параметр, правильно было написать команду так:

```bash
New-Item -Target 'C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe' -Path .\OHW.lnk -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

[-Path] Используется для результата, нужно было использовать [-Target] как параметр для задания пути откуда брать файл